# Update model when part of array vue3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api, v-model

How do I update an array when the model is in a loop for that array:

eg I have an array `const numbers = ref([1,2,3]);`

and I have a component that loops through the array using the values as the model:

```
<test v-for="(number, index) in numbers" :key="`${index}-${number}`" :number="number" @update:number="updateNumbers"></test>
```

If I update the number in that component:

```
emit('update:number', 5);
```

Why does it not update my original array?

Full code:

```html
//Main page
<script>
  import {
    defineComponent,
    ref
  } from 'vue'
  import Test from './Test.vue'
  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      Test,
    },
    setup() {
      const numbers = ref([1, 2, 3]);
      const updateNumbers = () => {
        console.log(numbers.value);
      };

      return {
        numbers,
        updateNumbers
      };
    },
  });
</script>

<template>
  <test v-for="(number, index) in numbers" :key="`${index}-${number}`" :number="number" @update:number="updateNumbers"></test>
</template> 



// Child Compnent
<script>
  import {
    defineComponent,
    ref
  } from 'vue'
  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'test',
    props: {
      number: {
        default: () => 0,
        required: true,
        type: Number,
      },
    },
    emits: [
      'update:number',
    ],
    setup(props, {
      emit
    }) {
      const updateNumber = () => {
        emit('update:number', 5);
      };

      return {
        updateNumber
      };
    },
  });
</script>

<template>
  <div @click="updateNumber">click {{ number }}</div>
</template>
```

[Working example on vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

If you click the text, I would expect the original array to have it's value replaced by 5 in the console.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cannot use the a `v-for` and `v-model` together on the same element.

If I use a `v-for` with an index on a parent element, I can then pass the indexed property of the array in to the child as the `v-model`:

```html
<div v-for="(number, index) in numbers" :key="`${index}-${number}`">     
    <test  v-model:number="numbers[index]" @update:number="updateNumbers"></test>
</div>
```

[Updated vue playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

You code is working fine, event payload is properly passed, you just did nothing with it.

If your intention was to emulate `v-model` behavior you must use `modelValue` as property: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

See [updated playground here](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)
[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - I was actually just trying to update the original array. If you have a look at my answer, I managed to do it without having to do anything extra with the emitted value

Comment: nice, v-model is quite useful, it did the trick for you